# How to install a gui in Fedora 23 Cloud

Tags: linux, fedora, graphical-user-interface, dnf

A little background - I'm trying to install oracle DB, and to do so I need a gui for the install.  After that I can get rid of it.

I'm running a Fedora 23 VM on digitalocean.   I have run `su -c 'dnf group install lxde-desktop'` which appears to install lxde, however when I reboot into the VNC connection, it does not boot to the gui.  Any ideas on why this wouldn't be running?

I tried to change the default target as well, and when I did that, it wouldn't boot at all!

Comment: Good god, why?!

Comment: Installing Oracle Database requires a GUI, as far as I know.  I just needed to use it to run the install, and can use the command line thereafter.

Comment: I'm so sorry you have to deal with Oracle. You may want to look into `dnf history undo` for reverting your changes. See also http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/107814/10618

Comment: Wow, Michael, I looked at that link, and apparently I don't even have to use KDE!  I had never thought to use an X window system remotely over ssh, but I set it up and it works!  Many thanks for the pointer!

Comment: After trying X window via ssh, my enthusiasm is tempered... It runs incredibly slow.

Comment: You don't even have to use X at all. Just do the silent installation with (or without) an answer file.

Answer (score 1):

Update: Found a much better solution: X2Go.  It's super easy to install.  Just run  `dnf install x2goserver`.  You also need to install lxde - to do so run `dnf install @lxde`.  Next download the X2Go client client for your os at http://wiki.x2go.org/doku.php/download:start.    Then connecting was simple and just worked.  It was much faster than the xemulation desktop or vnc.

=================

Found a good enough solution:

I installed KDE, logged in, and ran the command:

`startx`

and KDE started up.